# Page not found error on /album route

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm new at Zend Framework 2, i tried to develop a simple web page following the official guide here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/overview.html

When I try to go to the page /album, I can't find it. Can someone help me please?
The only thing I haven't done is to create a Virtual Host.

Code here:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/q9ddxicqa9bq3q2/html.zip

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, 
The problem it's the Virtual Host.
I created the zf2-tutorial.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled 
Now it works